# How can Python continuously fill multiple threads of subprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm running an app, foo, on Linux. From a Bash script/terminal prompt, my application runs multi-threaded with this command:

```
$ foo -config x.ini -threads 4 < inputfile
```

System Monitor and top report foo averages about 380% CPU load (quad-core machine). I've recreated this functionality in Python 2.6x with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("foo -config x.ini -threads 4", \
        shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
mylist = ['this','is','my','test','app','.']
for line in mylist:
    txterr = ''
    proc.stdin.write(line.strip()+'\n')
    while not proc.poll() and not txterr.count('Finished'):
        txterr += subproc.stderr.readline()
    print proc.stdout.readline().strip(),
```

Foo runs slower and top reports a CPU load of 100%. Foo also runs fine with shell=False, but still slow:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("foo -config x.ini -threads 4".split(), \
        shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, \
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Is there a way to have Python subprocess continuously fill all the threads?

Comment: Have you tried actually starting a new thread with python code, and executing the subprocess.Popen from within that new thread?

Comment: `not txterr.count('Finished')` ensures that the process can't process more than one input line at a time. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Sebastian. I want to keep foo busy on all four threads all the time. Exchange between sarnold below revealed foo indeed is running 4 threads, but each thread is only running 25% load. Piping lines to foo with Bash is more effecient than the Python loop.foo's output is very structured with status messages on stderr. Output is only present on stdout after stderr reports "Finished". If I don't retriev the stderr buffer, the whole process stalls after about 20-30 processed lines.

Comment: it is not a matter of a Python loop efficiency. You don't write *anything* to the `foo` process until you've encounted `'Finished'` in the stderr. To avoid deadlocks due to the os'es pipe buffer filling up either use `proc.communicate()` or use threads as in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802119/how-can-python-continuously-fill-multiple-threads-of-subprocess/4807193#4807193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your python script doesn't feed the `foo` process fast enough then you could offload reading stdout, stderr to threads:

```
from Queue import Empty, Queue
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading import Thread

def start_thread(target, *args):
    t = Thread(target=target, args=args)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t

def signal_completion(queue, stderr):
    for line in iter(stderr.readline, ''):
        if 'Finished' in line:
           queue.put(1) # signal completion
    stderr.close()

def print_stdout(q, stdout):
    """Print stdout upon receiving a signal."""
    text = []
    for line in iter(stdout.readline, ''):
        if not q.empty():
           try: q.get_nowait()               
           except Empty:
               text.append(line) # queue is empty
           else: # received completion signal              
               print ''.join(text),
               text = []
               q.task_done()
        else: # buffer stdout until the task is finished
            text.append(line)
    stdout.close()
    if text: print ''.join(text), # print the rest unconditionally

queue = Queue()
proc = Popen("foo -config x.ini -threads 4".split(), bufsize=1,
             stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
threads =  [start_thread(print_stdout, queue, proc.stdout)]
threads += [start_thread(signal_completion, queue, proc.stderr)]

mylist = ['this','is','my','test','app','.']
for line in mylist:
    proc.stdin.write(line.strip()+'\n')
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
for t in threads: t.join() # wait for stdout
```

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. I'm in the middle of running my work-around. I'll try this as soon as the system finishes.

Comment: @Sebastian - This worked like a champ. I also learned I don't really need the queue and signaling, but I left it in. It's a perfect solution and app is running full-speed. Thanks!

Comment: @tahoar: If you find an answer useful then click on the up-arrow on the left of the answer. If you think that the answer is acceptable (it answers your question completely) and the best among all answers then tick it off (accept it). http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 4):

When you call a command with Popen like this it doesn't matter if it's called from Python or from the shell. It's the "foo" command that starts it's processes, not Python.

So the answer is "Yes, subprocesses can be multi-threaded when called from Python."

Answer (score 1):

First things first, are you guessing it is single-threaded only because it is using 100% of CPU rather than 400%?

It would be better to check how many threads it has started using the `top` program, hit the `H` key to show threads. Or, use `ps -eLf` and make sure the `NLWP` column shows multiple threads.

Linux can be pretty twitchy with CPU affinity; by default, the scheduler will NOT move a process away from the last processor it used. Which means, if all four threads of your program were started on a single processor, they will ALL share the processor FOR EVER. You must use a tool like `taskset(1)` to *force* a CPU affinity on processes that must run on separate processors for a long time. e.g., `taskset -p <pid1> -c 0 ; taskset -p <pid2> -c 1 ; taskset -p <pid3> -c 2 ; taskset -p <pid4> -c 3`.

You can retrieve the affinity with `taskset -p <pid>` to find out what the affinity is currently set to.

(One day I wondered why my Folding At Home processes were using much less than CPU time I expected, I found that the bloody scheduler had placed three FaH tasks on ONE HyperThread sibling and the fourth FaH task on the other HT sibling *on the same core*. The other three processors were idle. (The first core also ran quite hot, and the other three cores were four or five degrees colder. Heh.))

Comment: Thanks sarnold. I used top -- hit H and found foo is running with 4 threads. In the case with Bash/terminal, each thread runs at close to 100% load. In the case with the Python loop, each thread runs at only 25% load. It appears to be a queue issue with foo, not a threading issue with Python or Linux. Any suggestions on how to queue several lines in Python before passing to foo? Thanks.

Comment: @tahoar Check each of those 25% load processes with `taskset -p <pid>`. I bet you'll find they are all stuffed on one processor and would run at full load if you forced them onto their own processors. I'm not sure what "queue several lines in python" means..

Comment: thanks again. You are correct, all processes were running with affinity mask = F. I forced them to specific CPU, e.g. taskset -p 0x0000000x <pid> -- and verified all were on different CPU with taskset -p <pid>. Still, even running on different CPU's each thread caps at 25% load. RE "queue"... From the shell, the foo program collects lines of data from the pipe (queue) and parses them to a thread. My Python code apparently acts differently than the shell and forces each line to complete before piping the next line of data.

Comment: @tahoar now I get it. :) The shell just sets up a redirection for your file, and passes a file descriptor to `foo`. You could try populating a file from your script and also hand the file descriptor to `foo`, and let it slurp the input as quickly as it wants. Or try `input = "\n".join(mylist) + "\n" ; proc.stdin.write(input)` and avoid the loop.